# Youtube gdata and search term having "&"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, youtube-api, gdata

I have the following code to let this program to search youtube gdata.

```
class Youtube
   def search_url(term)
     url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"
     url += "?q=#{term}&alt=json&restriction=US&max-results=50&orderby=viewCount"
 url += "&fields=entry(id,title,yt:noembed,media:group(media:description),author(name),yt:statistics(@viewCount))"
     url += "&key=#{DEV_KEY}"
```

However, when I tested this program, it seems it fails to search when the search term contains "&", like the popular duo artist "Macklemore & Ryan Lewis".

"&" might not be the cause of failure. But I just suspect it. If you think "&" is not the cause, what do you think is the cause of failure? If you think "&" is the cause, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need the escape the term before sending it as a URL parameter:

```
require 'cgi'

def search_url(term)
  term = CGI.escape(term)
  url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"
  url += "?q=#{term}&alt=json&restriction=US&max-results=50&orderby=viewCount"
  url += "&fields=entry(id,title,yt:noembed,media:group(media:description),author(name),yt:statistics(@viewCount))"
  url += "&key=#{DEV_KEY}"
```

escaping using [`CGI.escape`](http://moxleystratton.com/article/ruby-escape-unescape-encode-decode-html-xml-uri-url) results in a URI-safe parameter:

```
CGI.escape('Macklemore & Ryan Lewis')
# => "Macklemore+%26+Ryan+Lewis"
```

Comment: @Uri_Agassi Thank you. But your code now doesn't include "class Youtube". But perhaps that doesn't mean "class Youtube" should be really deleted, right?

Comment: Of course class Youtube _should_ be there... I just got lazy copying your cose

Comment: @Uri_Agassi Uh... I tested the program but it didn't work. In fact now the program can't search the things that it could search before. Any idea what happened?

Comment: what is the resulting query? how is it different from the query that worked?

Comment: @Uri_Agassi Query is "Macklemore & Ryan Lewis".

If you open this

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Macklemore & Ryan Lewis&restriction=US&max-results=50&orderby=viewCount

by Firefox, then you can see "Macklemore - Thrift Shop Ft. Wanz Lyrics On Screen" appears in the list, which isn't supposed to appear, because it doesn't contain "Ryan Lewis"

Comment: @Uri_Agassi I also tried

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Macklemore+%26+Ryan+Lewis&restriction=US&max-results=50&orderby=viewCount

because your code seems to change "Macklemore & Ryan Lewis" to "Macklemore+%26+Ryan+Lewis".

But "Macklemore - Thrift Shop Ft. Wanz Lyrics On Screen" appears in the list again.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not in my domain of expertise - it is part of the API definition, and not passing the query _to_ the API...